# How to display all orders for a single product showing the most recent first? Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a password protected page on the frontend. On that page, I want to display a full list of all purchases associated with a single woocommerce product id.

Option 1:

I've looked through the [woocommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/index.html), and I found: 
[WC_CLI_Order](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_CLI_Order.html) and a `list_( $args, $assoc_args )` function that lists all orders.

Presumably, the orders can be filtered by `product id`

[--=]
Filter orders based on order property.

Line item fields (numeric array, started with index zero):

```
line_items.0.product_id
```

Option 2:

I [found this article](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/get-all-woocommerce-orders-for-a-customer/), but it is based on the customer id.  I've modified the code based on guesses for meta_key and meta_value.

```
$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key'    => '_product',
    'meta_value'  => get_product_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
) );
```

How do I display all orders for a single product showing the most recent order first?

Comment: have you tried changing the query to get purchases based on your product? like get_purchases( array('product' => 'pencil')) where it is building a query toy your needs. i am not an expert on woocommerce. but i think these array is supposed to be a query keys like meta_value is not needed if its not in your table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution I put together based on these articles:

- http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/#
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-show-all-orders-details-for-specific-or-particular-product-in-woocommerce-1/
- https://www.gavick.com/blog/wp_query-woocommerce-products

Solution

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ ?>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$produto_id = 41; // Product ID
$consulta = "SELECT order_id " .
            "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim " .
            "LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items oi " .
            "ON woim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id " .
            "WHERE meta_key = '_product_id' AND meta_value = %d " .
            "GROUP BY order_id;";

$order_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( $consulta, $produto_id ) );

foreach( $order_ids as $order_id ) {
    var_dump($order_id);
}

if( $order_ids ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'post__in' => $order_ids,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'shop_order_status',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array (
                    'Pending' , 'Failed' , 'Processing' , 'Completed', 'On-Hold' , 'Cancelled' , 'Refunded'
                )
            )
        )
    );
    $wc_query = new WP_Query( $args );
}

?>

// Display products
<div>
    <?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : // (4)
                    $wc_query->the_post(); // (4.1) ?>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <?php the_title(); // (4.2) ?>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // (5) ?>
    <?php else:  ?>
    <p>
         <?php _e( 'No Orders' ); // (6) ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, worked great for my needs. Just a note, WooCommerce > 2.2 no longer uses taxonomies for order statuses. You should use post_status instead.